# How do I set up surface pressure as function of time due to atmospheric erosion by Solar wind?

Tags: atmospheric-science, solar-wind

It is known that highly energetic particles from the sun when striking a planet ionize the atmospheric particles and the ions may escape the planet by being guided by the solar magnetic flux that grazes the planet. In this way solar wind causes atmospheric erosion. The decrease in atmospheric mass causes the atmospheric pressure to decrease. How do I express the decrease of surface pressure as a function of time when the solar wind causes atmospheric erosion? I know that solar wind has its fluctuating intensities. But is there a general case?

Comment: Solar winds occur randomly so you probably will not be able express its effects on anything in terms of a function of time.

Comment: @joseph is it possible then with asteroid impacts?

Comment: Well I guess you would run into the same problem in that when objects strike the earth will also be non-deterministic.

Comment: Also, on the surface, volcanoes, oceans, and various life forms (including man) add or remove various elements of the atmosphere.

Comment: An entire NASA flagship mission was launched to try and answer this question (called MAVEN).  You could start by searching articles using data from that mission, otherwise the answer to this question would be a very large book I think...